# React native (expo) error message: require is not defined

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm suddenly getting this error in my code. I can't pinpoint what caused it, because when I went to bed it was working. When I started again in the morning, I suddenly got this error message:

`abi35_0_0.com.facebook.react.common.javascriptexception: require is not defined`

My project is fairly new, and I have mostly just been scaffolding. There is not much to show, but I have commented out any code that could potentially cause issue. I even went so far as to go back 3 or so commits, when the app was 100% working properly, yet the issue persists.

Digging around online suggests that `babel` may contain the issue, so here is my `.babelrc`

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "modules": false,
                "useBuiltIns": "usage",
                "corejs": 3
            }
        ],
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "module-resolver",
            {
                "root": [
                    "./src"
                ],
                "extensions": [
                    ".ios.js",
                    ".android.js",
                    ".js",
                    ".json"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from"
    ]
}
```

and `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

It's been several hours of scouring the internet for a solution, and I feel progress has stopped. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I had the same error message that I found was misleading in my case. Take a closer look at your require() statement. You can't pass dynamic string to it. The path to the required file has to be static. So this will NOT work: require(`./assets/${filename}`)

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I am facing the same issue, thank you in advance and regards